# Access variables in an overloaded function from its parent

Tags: php, oop

I''ve run into a slight issue, and cant' seem to find any documentation on how to fix, or whether it's even possible. Here's some sample code of what I'm trying to do.

```
class Foo {
public function A ($dynamicValues) {
$var = array($dynamicValues);
}
}

class MyClass extends Foo {
public function A {
var_dump($var);
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access the values declared in the parent class's function A in the $var array, that contains a dynamic array that is passed to it. However, I'm unable to find a way to do so, as the var_dump returns $var as an empty array. The closest thing I've found that will achieve my goal would be to set $var in the parent class as static, but since the values it accepts are not static, I believe that would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve but depending on the context you can use either of these methods :

If you don't want to know how Foo:A() computes $var and $var is what is returned by the function, you can call it from the *overriding* method MyClass:A() like this

```
class Foo {
    public function A($dynamicValues) {
        return array($dynamicValues);
    }
}

class MyClass extends Foo {
    public function A($dynamicValues) {
        $vars = parent::A($dynamicValues);
        var_dump($vars);
    }
}
```

If A() returns something else than $var, you can extract a method from Foo::A() to compute $var like this :

```
class Foo {
    public function A($dynamicValues) {
        $var = $this->_getVar($dynamicValues);
    }

    protected function _getVar($dynamicValues) {
        return array($dynamicValues);
    }
}

class MyClass extends Foo {
    public function A($dynamicValues) {
        $var = $this->_getVar($dynamicValues);
        var_dump($var);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking the former might be the way to go here. Looking back on it after a while, I think the layout that I had originally was not built correctly.

Answer (score 2):

the variable you are trying to "access" isnt defined in your scope.

the whole function gets overloaded. variables inside functions belong to this function and are not available elswher eif you are not dealing with globals.

you should define a class variable like so:

```
class Foo {
    protected $var = "hello";
}

class MyClass extends Foo {
    public function A {
        var_dump($this->var); // will output hello
    }
}
```